# Load/point to a PostGIS table within expression interface in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, labeling, qgis-expression

With QGIS 3, in order to limit the number of labels to my "town" table intersecting my area of interest polygon, I wanted to test the QGIS expression called: "overlay_intersects" via the settings / label / rendering menu. The syntax of the expression seems quite simple. But when I do an "overlay_intersects("my_table")" the expression is said to be invalid and my PostGIS table could not be loaded.

What is good practice with QGIS expression interface to load, point to a PostGIS table? Do I need to enter the server name? the name of the db? of the scheme? FYI, my common table is stored in 'admin' schema.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, are you trying to load a subset of point (and labelling this subset) or to label a subset a point (but loading all of them) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  understand you want to selectively show/hide the labels of your point layer, based on the spatial intersection with another polygon layer.

You can indeed use `overlay_intersects()`, but you need to use single quotes around the layer name, not double quotes

Let's note that it happens with any layers, not only PostGIS ones.

[image]

PS: and here is the error when using double quotes

[image]